# laravel eloquent foreach loop error Trying to get property 'location_id' of non-object

Tags: php, eloquent

This one has happened to me before but I have no idea why and how to avoid it. So I have a static function in a Model which gets all the database rows and uses a foreach loop to read another table but I am unable to correctly read the row data:

```
    public static function test()
    {
        $accounts = self::where( 'is_enabled', 1 )->get();
        foreach ( $accounts as $account ) {
            $map      = AccountMap::where( 'account_id', $account->id )->first();
            $location = Location::getLocation( $map->location_id );
            $data     = $location->getData();
        }
    }
```

So the above function gathers an array of items ($accounts) this is then passed into a foreach loop all is fine to this point but if i now use $account->id it is null. The id is shown in the Account object in its attributes folder.

A very similar function is used elsewhere in this model but it uses a passed id and this one works (however $account->id is null). The issue is not the database or column names:

```
    public static function getThisLocation( $id )
    {
        $account = self::find( $id );
        $map     = AccountMap::where( 'account_id', $id )->first();
        location = Location::getLocation( $map->location_id );
        $data    = $location->getData();

        return $data;

    }
```

*** EDIT ***
Account, AccountMap and Location are all Eloquent models

```
namespace App\Models;
use Eloquent;
use App\Notifications\AccountMessages;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

/**
 * @method static find(int $id)
 */
class Account extends Eloquent
{
    use Sortable;
    use Notifiable;

public $sortable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'lastupdate',
        'url'
    ];

public static function test()
    {
        $accounts = self::where( 'is_enabled', 1 )->get();
        foreach ( $accounts as $account ) {
            $map      = AccountMap::where( 'account_id', $account->id )->first();
            $location = Location::getLocation( $map->location_id );
            $data     = $location->getData();
        }
    }

    public static function getThisLocation( $id )
    {
        $account = self::find( $id );
        $map     = AccountMap::where( 'account_id', $id )->first();
        location = Location::getLocation( $map->location_id );
        $data    = $location->getData();

        return $data;

    }

}
```

```
namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;

/**
 * @method static where(string $string, int $id)
 */
class AccountMap extends Eloquent
{
    use Sortable;

    public $sortable = [
        'id',
        'account_id',
        'location'
    ];

}
```

*** MORE EDIT ***
I have confirmed that using $account->attributes['id'] has worked but I've no idea why what I expected to work didn't ($account->id)

Comment: So `$map` is not an object. Therefore `$map = AccountMap::where( 'account_id', $account->id )->first();` either does not return an Object or it has failed to return anything

Comment: the issue is $account->id is returning null and so $map cannot find the data

Comment: Which version are we talking about here? Because I think that should be `extends Model`, which eventually may even answer the recent update to the question ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be something related to communication of your model and migration.

Add this dd() to your current test function:

```
 public static function test()
    {
        $accounts = self::where( 'is_enabled', 1 )->get();
        foreach ( $accounts as $account ) {
            if ($account->id){
                $map      = AccountMap::where( 'account_id', $account->id )->first();
                $location = Location::getLocation( $map->location_id );
                $data     = $location->getData();
            } else {
             dd($account)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then Check the result and see is there the id filed on your response? If not, The id field doesn't exist on your self Model and it's Your problem's cause.

Finally, Check your model fields easily with :

```
 public function testReturnOfSelfModel()
    {
        $data= self::all();
        dd($data);
    }
```

If you have id on this dd function, Your Model working properly. If not, you dont have id field.

Also, it is more professional to change Capitalize your model's first charachter. It sholud be Self, not self.

Comment: All of the Models are eloquent in this test. I mention in the question that the model has anarray attributes which has the column items in it (i.e. it appears that $account->attributes['id'] would work but surely this should work with $account->id right?

Comment: it should works. did you re-run test() with dd($account) like I said? If yes, put answer here to see

Comment: Hi Mohammad, The result is an array of 100 rows of the Account model, each one has an attribute array in it and it also has other fields including id. Although the id exists in the attributes array it is set as null in the object itself. But why would this be the case? my other eloquent models are right and as expected (```$map = AccountMap::where( 'account_id', 5 )->first(); echo $map->location_id;```) which returns 5 in this case. I posted the Account model above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to setup two proper data `Model` (a migration would need to create these tables):

```
class Account extends Model {

    protected $table = 'accounts';

    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

}
```

Unless defining `protected $table` it will definitely not know what to do.

It's rather unclear what you're even trying to accomplish with `AcountMap`, but it may need a relation defined; which eg. with `return $this->belongsTo(Account::class);` ...while simply adding `lat` & `lng` to `class Account` would be far less complex and perfectly fine, while it's only 1 `location`.

Comment: I agree this could be done better and foreign keys can be added. This is just a test of concept which I've come across in other projects. Using the above code seems to break the model with this simple test. I am able to correctly get data from the database if i add the id, The data is already migrated/seeded, This test project displays these results in a paginated table. I've ommitted the controller and views for brevity.  The data returns the rows in an array in the object called attributes and not as an object. $model->id doesn't work but $model->attributes['id'] does which is not expected.